# How do rewrite this higher order function without using static functions?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, higher-order-functions

The functionality that I'm looking for works flawlessly here with the static function syntax, however, I like the static functions declared on the constructor itself (i.e. `className.staticFunction () => ...` instead of `static staticFunction = () => ...` within the class definition itself.

Here's the code I'm referring to that I'd like to refactor to use the static functions defined on the constructor/function rather than the `static` syntax as seen below.

```
const higherOrderFunction = another => andAnother => class extends Component {

  static functionName = {
    test: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, World!</h1>;
  }
};

export default higherOrderFunction;
```

Comment: Where are you using `another` and `andAnother`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a `class` is the same as the constructor `function` you'd define without classes. So:

```
const higherOrderFunction = another => andAnother => Component;

function Component() {}

Component.functionName = () => {
  test: React.PropTypes.object
};

Component.prototype.render = () => {
  return <h1>Hello, World!</h1>;
}

export default higherOrderFunction;
```

You may want to wrap the function and member definitions in the function body to encapsulate and use any arguments:

```
const higherOrderFunction = another => andAnother => {
  function Component() {}

  Component.functionName = () => {
    test: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  Component.prototype.render = () => {
    return <h1>Hello, World! {another} and {andAnother}</h1>;
  }

  return Component;
};

export default higherOrderFunction;
```

Comment: This makes sense, however, I was wondering if there's anyway to achieve this with ES6 classes.

Comment: Yes. Instead of defining a function you just define a class. You can tack static functions onto that later as well.